# Changed stack pointer and C library calls

Tags: c, windows, cygwin, x86-64

I have an application consisting of C code and x64 assembly.

In the beginning of the main function (written in C) virtual memory is allocated.
Then assembly procedure is called. In that procedure stack pointer is changed to the allocated memory. The assembly procedure eventually calls function like write(), printf(), fflush().

When printf() followed by fflush() are called, the program sometimes crashes, and sometimes writes wrong characters to stdout.

When I remove code for changing stack pointer, the issue will gone.

Are there any peculiarities for handling stack pointers for Windows programs?

Note. I know about allocating 32 bytes of 'shadow space' on stack before calling C functions from assembly.

I use cygwin and gcc to build the program.

main.c:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <string.h>

#define wordSize 8
#define fixnumShift 0x02
typedef uint64_t ptr;

extern int schemeEntry();

char* allocateProtectedSpace(int size) {
    SYSTEM_INFO si;
    GetSystemInfo(&si);
    int pageSize = si.dwPageSize;
    int aligned = (size + pageSize - 1) / pageSize * pageSize;
    int total = aligned + pageSize * 2;
    char* pBase = (char*) VirtualAlloc(0, total, MEM_RESERVE, PAGE_NOACCESS);
    char* pSpace = (char*) VirtualAlloc(pBase + pageSize, aligned, MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_READWRITE);
    return pSpace;
}

void printPtr(ptr p) {
    int n = (int) p;
    printf("%d", n >> fixnumShift);
    fflush(stdout);
}

int main() {
    int stackSize = 16 * 4096;
    char* stack = allocateProtectedSpace(stackSize);
    char* stackHigherAddr = stack + stackSize - wordSize;
    printPtr(schemeEntry(stackHigherAddr));
    return 0;
}
```

schemeMain.s

```
    .text
    .globl schemeEntry
    schemeEntry:
    pushq %r15
    movq %rsp, %r15
    movq %rcx, %rsp
    pushq %rbp
    pushq %r15
    pushq %r14
    pushq %r13
    pushq %r12
    pushq %rbx

    subq $104, %rsp

    movq $4, 96(%rsp)
    movq 96(%rsp), %rcx
    subq $32, %rsp
    call printPtr
    addq $32, %rsp

    addq $104, %rsp

    popq %rbx
    popq %r12
    popq %r13
    popq %r14
    popq %r15
    popq %rbp
    movq %r15, %rsp
    popq %r15
    retq
```

Just showing excerpt from code, to show how stack initialization is done.

Comment: Do you set the stack pointer to that *top* of the allocated space? In x86, the stack grows downward. Do you make sure that the new stack pointer is 16 byte aligned?

Comment: Would it not be more clear if you just showed the code you are describing? In fact, it is really kind of a per-requisite if  you need any kind of a precise answer to your questions.  ( [mcve] )  If you decide to edit the post to meet [minimums for asking a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), post me a comment so I can remove my vote to close.

Comment: How much stack memory do you reserve?  Windows needs "stack probes" if you might grow the stack by more than 4kiB in one allocation.  https://geidav.wordpress.com/tag/stack-probing/

Comment: @prl, seems that the issue was that top of the stack was 8 byte aligned, not 16 byte

Comment: @prl, so each time I call C function I must align stack pointer to 16 byte boundary?

Comment: @EricPostpischil - Thanks, removed comment.

Comment: what sense change stack space to another ? and you not change info about this in *TEB* - as result say exception handlers will be not work after this.

Comment: Hanik, generally the stack is aligned at the beginning and then each function maintains that alignment by making sure that the stack pointer always changes by a multiple of 16.  Since a call puts an 8-byte return address on the stack, the prologue of each function subtracts an odd multiple of 8 (that is, a multiple of 16 plus 8) to maintain 16 byte alignment.

Comment: RbMm, the reason is that stack area here is surrounded by two protected pages, so the program will crash early if it tries to access the memory locations below or above the stack

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved by maintaining 16 byte alignment for the stack pointer.